# Unable to install opencv in raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

i have tried installing opencv on my raspberry pi using

```
sudo apt install python-opencv libopencv-dev
```

but i receive an error 404 not found accelerator error. the same error 404 pops when i'm trying to `sudo apt upgrade`.

I have also tried using

```
pip install opencv
```

but it's still not installed.

can someone help me resolve this 404 not found on accelerator error.

Comment: which version or OS are you using?, also please post the exact error

Comment: Here is link w/out compile. https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/